# Liferay 7, osgi module for mvc portlet doesnt find dependencies

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I've start the new module for Liferay 7 GA1 using

```
blade create -t portlet -p com.liferay.docs.portlet -c MyPortlet my-portlet-project
```

This is my gradle.build

```
dependencies {
    compile group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "2.0.0"
    compile group: "javax.portlet", name: "portlet-api", version: "2.0"
    compile group: "javax.servlet", name: "servlet-api", version: "2.5"
    compile group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.compendium", version: "5.0.0"

    compile group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.my.account.web", version: "1.0.2"
    compile group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.users.admin.web", version: "1.0.4"
}
```

In the portal the module com.liferay.my.account.web is at 1.0.2 version, but in the repository https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/liferay-ce/com/liferay/com.liferay.my.account.web/ the version is still 1.0.1

Building the module I have this error:

```
λ gradle build
:modules:my-mvc-portlet-project:compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':modules:my-mvc-portlet-project:compile'.
> Could not find com.liferay:com.liferay.my.account.web:1.0.2.
  Searched in the following locations:
      http://cdn.repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/liferay/com.liferay.my.account.web/1.0.2/com.liferay.my.account.web-1.0.2.pom
      http://cdn.repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/liferay/com.liferay.my.account.web/1.0.2/com.liferay.my.account.web-1.0.2.jar
  Required by:
  plugins-sdk-7.0.modules:my-mvc-portlet-project:1.0.0
```

Setting versione 1.0.1 for com.liferay.my.account.web the gradle build is ok, but the deploy process fails with:

```
λ blade deploy
stop 503
update 503 file:/C:/java/projects/LF7x/workspace/plugins-sdk-7.0/modules/my-mvc-portlet-project/build/libs/my.mvc.portlet.project-1.0.0.jar
Updated bundle 503
start 503
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: my.mvc.portlet.project [503]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.my.account.web.portlet.action
```

The complete source code here:
https://github.com/baxtheman/liferay7GA1-sandbox/tree/master/modules

Liferay forum question:
https://web.liferay.com/it/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/73513613

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved by myself, look at liferay forum:

https://liferay.dev/ask/questions/development/liferay-7-osgi-module-for-mvc-portlet-doesnt-find-dependencies-1